# Android How to Delete an android sqlite Database entry

Tags: android, sqlite

This works to Insert a Row

```
             public long insertRows(Double lat, Double log, String mdate,
             String mycomment, String name) {
        ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
            value.put(COLUMN2,lat);
           //System.out.println(COLUMN2+lat);
            value.put(COLUMN3, log);
           //System.out.println(COLUMN3+log);
            value.put(COLUMN4, mdate);
           //System.out.println(COLUMN4+mdate);
           value.put(COLUMN5, mycomment);
           //String mycomment = null;
           //System.out.println(COLUMN5+mycomment);
           value.put(COLUMN6, name);
           return db.insert(TABLENAME,null,value);}
```

But I am unable to Delete a row programmatically.

I can provide more code or info if needed any help is greatly appreciated

this is what Im useing so far seems intemitant though 
and Im still haveing issues updateing the listactivity

```
             public boolean deleteEntry(long Id) {Id = GpsListactivity.rowid;   
             System.out.println("GPSDATABASE "+ TABLENAME + KEY_ROWID + "=" +Id);
             return db.delete(TABLENAME,KEY_ROWID + "="+Id,null) > 0;}
```

// this is the update method

```
             public boolean update(long Id, Double lat, Double log,
             String mdate,String mycomment, String name) {
        ContentValues updateValues = createContentValues(
             lat,log,mdate,mycomment,name);
        return db.update(TABLENAME, updateValues,"locationId=?" +Id,null) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)`.  For example:

```
String whereClause = "COLUMN4 = 'value'";
db.delete(TABLENAME, whereClause, null);
```

To delete a specific row, you will have to know information about that row which makes it unique (for example the row's primary key or a combination of data in its columns).

You can also reference the [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) documentation for more information.